Why is Caja rearranging what I type?
(It would have been 'next question' except my posting is rationed -- I'm only allowed to have issues at a preset rate.)
I noticed it most clearly in using the multiple file 'Rename' with the 'Replace' tab.  Characters were rather scrambled;  I found I needed to type each character and wait as much as a second to type the next character to get them in the order I typed them.
I saw several times, as I waited, that Caja does not immediately display the character I typed, but does so after a brief pause, but does not move the cursor after the character until after another significant pause. So if I type a character before it moves the cursor, it seems the characters end up in the wrong place.
I think (because it seems to sometimes mess up a filename in the input of a single file rename) it does something similar in other situations.
It's significantly worse when Caja is also sucking up cycles doing ... something (previous question).
Is there some setting that will cause Caja to behave normally and process input in an orderly fashion?
Release 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.18.10-76051810-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0
Caja 1.24.0
